# OrderBy int slow for large table join

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

I have roughly 1.5 million records.  This query works fine for smaller data, but it gets a second slower for every few hundred thousand records. For 1.5 million, the query is noticeably struggling.

I mocked up a whole new Code First project to verify the problem is independent of my implementation, and to provide this example query:

```
    SELECT TOP 1 Widgets.*
    FROM [WidgetSandbox].[dbo].[Widgets] Widgets
    INNER JOIN [WidgetSandbox].[dbo].[Status] Statuses ON Widgets.StatusId = Statuses.Id
    INNER JOIN [WidgetSandbox].[dbo].[Colors] Colors ON Widgets.ColorCode = Colors.ColorCode
    INNER JOIN [WidgetSandbox].[dbo].[Sizes] Sizes ON Widgets.SizeId = Sizes.Id
    WHERE Statuses.Name = 'Available'
    AND Colors.Name = 'Red'
    ORDER BY Sizes.DiameterInches
```

DiameterInches is an `int`, as a metaphor for "PriorityLevel" in my actual code.

If I comment out `ORDER BY Sizes.DiameterInches`, it returns immediately, but if I want to find "the smallest available red widget", then it crawls.

Is there a better way?

[image]

Execution plan XML: https://gist.github.com/RobertBaldini/57c8b61d135cc5c84c38b2da243611ad

DDL: https://gist.github.com/RobertBaldini/3740c7bb85eea47d7fe63cb8602ac2d6

Repo (data loader takes several minutes): https://github.com/RobertBaldini/WidgetSandbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should retype the various *Name* columns from *nvarchar(max)* to *nvarchar([right size])*. It's unlikely that names will be up to 2GB in length, and making them *max* sized prevents them being used as a key in an index. A good general rule of thumb is to avoid large object data types wherever possible.

You'll probably need to make that change to the EF code, but in T-SQL:

```
-- Guessing at 100 characters maximum
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Status]
ALTER COLUMN Name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Colors
ALTER COLUMN Name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Sizes
ALTER COLUMN Name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Widgets
ALTER COLUMN Name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL;
```

I have also changed the column definition to `NOT NULL` there.

Anyway, given indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_dbo_Sizes__DiameterInches
ON dbo.Sizes (DiameterInches);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_dbo_Widgets__SizeId_ColorCode_StatusId__Name
ON dbo.Widgets (SizeId, ColorCode, StatusId)
INCLUDE (Name);
```

...you should end up with a plan that avoids lookups and sorts, something like:

[image: Expected plan shape]

With the small number of rows in *Status* and *Colors*, it is probably not worth indexing their *Name* columns right now, but that could change over time. In any case, if the name columns should be unique, you should constrain them to be so using a unique constraint or unique nonclustered index, for example:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UQ_dbo_Colors__Name
ON dbo.Colors (Name);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UQ_dbo_Status__Name
ON dbo.[Status] (Name);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UQ_dbo_Sizes__Name
ON dbo.Sizes (Name);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UQ_dbo_Widgets__Name
ON dbo.Widgets (Name);
```

#### Second approach

With the same indexes, if you are able to change the SQL, you could also separate out the *Color* and *Status* lookups:

```
DECLARE 
    @StatusId integer,
    @ColorCode nvarchar(6);

SELECT @StatusId = ST.Id 
FROM dbo.[Status] AS ST 
WHERE ST.Name = N'Available';

SELECT @ColorCode = C.ColorCode 
FROM dbo.Colors AS C 
WHERE C.Name = N'Red';

SELECT TOP (1) 
    W.*
FROM dbo.Widgets AS W
JOIN dbo.Sizes AS S
    ON W.SizeId = S.Id
WHERE
    W.StatusId = @StatusId
    AND W.ColorCode = @ColorCode
ORDER BY
    S.DiameterInches;
```

This makes for a simpler set of operations that also happen to make life easier for the optimizer:

[image: Plan with lookups separate]

Note also that Unicode string literals should be prefixed with N for correct data typing.

Oh, and you should also patch your instance. It is currently SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1 - [Service Pack 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44278) has been available for some time now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that TopN Sort in the top left. It has to pull in all possible rows to then find the smallest one.

If you have an index on *DiameterInches*, it's likely to start searching on the smallest ones first, and give you vastly improved performance.

Of course, then you'll need an index on *Widgets.SizeId*, so that it can find those easily. And it'll need to check each one to see if it's Red and Available. You might find it's a little over-normalised. If "Available" means StatusId = 'A', then use that, for example.

A suitable index might be:

```
CREATE INDEX ixDiameterInches 
ON dbo.Sizes (DiameterInches, Id)
```

But also consider having:

```
CREATE INDEX ixSizeStatusColor 
ON dbo.Widgets (SizeId, StatusId, ColorCode);
```

...so that you can quickly find those Available Red small things. You may find that `(StatusId, ColorCode, SizeId)` works better if you don't have many Available Red things.