# Update with CTE & OUTPUT blocks on concurrent calls

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, locking, deadlock, concurrency

I was having deadlock issues, so I started using this CTE trick that I read somewhere. No more deadlocks.

But now each client that I add slows down (blocks?) the stored procedure. E.g. a 1-2 second update with 1 client becomes 2-4 seconds for two clients. (This simple metaphor query runs at 0.001 seconds, but gets up to like 0.03 after a handful of clients -- so the issue is independent of my real-world implementation.)

Is it a locking issue? Do I need to wrap it in a (some kind of) transaction?

```
WITH UpdateView AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 W.*
    FROM [WidgetSandbox].[dbo].[Widgets] W
    INNER JOIN [WidgetSandbox].[dbo].[Sizes] S ON W.SizeId = S.Id
    WHERE W.StatusId = @availableStatusId
    AND W.ColorCode = @colorCode
    ORDER BY S.DiameterInches
)

UPDATE UpdateView 
SET StatusId = @soldOutStatusId
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @outputIds;

SET @singleUpdatedId = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM @outputIds);

SELECT * FROM [WidgetSandbox].[dbo].[Widgets]
WHERE Id = @singleUpdatedId;
```

I wish I had a better idea of what the specific problem is, but as it is I'm just stuck....

DDL, if it helps: https://gist.github.com/RobertBaldini/3740c7bb85eea47d7fe63cb8602ac2d6

Repo: https://github.com/RobertBaldini/WidgetSandbox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many of the issues you see are being caused by an inefficient execution plan:

[image: Supplied plan]

Not that the supplied plan and query matches the question, but even so, I'm working with what was provided.

Anyway, you should implement the *Name* column data type changes (from *nvarchar(max)*) that I mentioned in your [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/135211/1192). More importantly, you need to *add the indexes I recommended*, so the row to update can be found without sorting:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_dbo_Sizes__DiameterInches
ON dbo.Sizes (DiameterInches);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_dbo_Widgets__SizeId_ColorCode_StatusId__Name
ON dbo.Widgets (SizeId, ColorCode, StatusId)
INCLUDE (Name);
```

You can then update the status of the selected item and return the row affected with:

```
DECLARE
    -- Constant values guessed, replace with the real ones
    @availableStatusId integer = 1,
    @soldOutStatusId integer= 9,
    @colorCode nvarchar(6) = N'Red';

WITH UpdateView AS 
(
    SELECT TOP (1)
        W.Id,
        W.Name,
        W.StatusId,
        W.ColorCode,
        W.SizeId
    FROM dbo.Widgets AS W WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST)
    JOIN dbo.Sizes AS S 
        ON W.SizeId = S.Id
    WHERE 
        W.StatusId = @availableStatusId
        AND W.ColorCode = @colorCode
    ORDER BY 
        S.DiameterInches
)
UPDATE UpdateView 
SET StatusId = @soldOutStatusId
OUTPUT
    Inserted.Id,
    Inserted.Name,
    Inserted.StatusId,
    Inserted.ColorCode,
    Inserted.SizeId;
```

Note the `UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST` hints there. These are the standard hints needed for concurrent FIFO access to queue-type tables. See [Using Tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) by Remus Rusanu for more information.

The execution plan shape you should get (with no sorts!) is:

[image: Update plan]

As an aside, unless you have very good reasons, your database should not be using `SET AUTO_CLOSE ON`.